# awk command doesn't work under /bin/sh -c

Tags: python, awk

I'm using this command:

> docker ps | awk '$2 ~ /^selenium/ { print $1 }'

which works fine in the shell, but when running it with `sh -c` it doesn't work and I'm getting this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1:  ~ /^selenium/ { print  }
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error
```

The full command that I want to is part from a Python script:

```
os.popen("nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh -c \"docker ps | awk -F/ '\''$2 ~ /^selenium/ { print $1 }'\''\"")
```

It's probably some escaping problem but I couldn't solve any.

Comment: Not sure what `nsenter` does here, but you can avoid many shenanigans like these by using `docker run --name selenium` when starting the container; then `docker ps --filter name=selenium -q` should give you a the container ID directly.

Answer (score 3):

You've got several levels of quoting there that are causing problems. If you start by using Python triple-quotes on the outside (`'''` or `"""`), you can reduce the amount of escaping you need to perform.

That gets us:

```
os.popen('''nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh -c "docker ps | awk -F/ '\$2 ~ /^selenium/ { print \$1 }'"''')
```

We still need to escape the `$` because otherwise they would be escaped by the outer shell (the one that `os.popen` calls to run the command).

I'm a little supicious of the `-F/` in your `awk` command, but I assume you've tested this out and confirmed it turns the output you want.

---

By using the `subprocess` module, which doesn't call `/bin/sh` by default, you can further reduce the escaping (at the expense of having to tokenize the command line yourself):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output([
    'nsenter', '-t', '1', '-m', '-u', '-n', '-i', 
    'sh', '-c', "docker ps | awk  -F/ '$2 ~ /^selenium/ { print $1 }'"
])
```

Comment: You can use `shlex.split()` to tokenize the command for you if you are not comfortable doing it yourself. (I'm not entirely sure it's going to behave correctly for nontrivial nested quoting, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have trying: `... awk -F/ '\\$2 ~ /^s...`

(double backslash before $2)